# Recovery Mode will not load

Tags: windows-7, windows, safe-mode

My computer broke over the weekend.  I came in and it was on the "setup windows" screen.

Now I can't even get safe mode to boot. Stalls on classpnp.sys.  All the help for this uses recovery mode.

So I wanted to launch recovery mode to try to fix it.  But that is not working too.

I have tried via F8, a recovery disk and using the Win 7 disk.

Each time it says it is loading, but once it gets done, it shows an empty (black) screen.  The monitor is still on, but the screen is blank.

Any ideas how I can get into recovery mode?

Comment: What type of computer, brand and model? Any error messages or beeping?

Comment: Can you see the mouse pointer?

Comment: @mok no mouse pointer

Comment: @charlierb the computer is a custom built one.  (By another company that we hire out to.)

Comment: Ok. What about error messages or POST beeps? Is the company you purchased it from able to assist?

Comment: @Charlierb No errors.  Just stuck on classpnp.sys.  My IT support team can "assist" by reinstalling my os.  I am hoping for a less destructive fix.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure reinstalling the OS will fix the issue if it won't completely boot from a recovery disk or Windows disk. Hardware diagnostics should be done before reinstalling the OS.

Answer (score 0):

If you have you Windows 7 Repair Disk Why dont you try using that, 
if you dont have one then you can always burn one to a disk or flash drive.

also when you reboot the same os if will show you all your Drive partitions so you can basically just keep all your old stuff and creat a new partition for your OS to be installed onto and then when you get onto the computer transfer your stuff over and delete the old OS, Thats what i did.

The only other thing i can thing of is removing the CMOS battery to refresh the BIOS so that you may be able to get it to boot safe mode.

Hope this helps

Comment: As I said in my question, I tried the Repair disk.  When I boot from it, I get the loading screen, then a blank screen (black with the back lights on).  I tried booting with another disk drive, and the first is there but I cannot access it. (See: http://superuser.com/q/730227/2183 and http://superuser.com/q/730243/2183).  I have not tried pulling the battery because it is a file issue that is failing, not the BIOS.

Comment: do you not have a cloud storage or anything that would make it possible to back up temporary

Comment: It does not matter if I can or cannot back up to the cloud (which I can't), because I cannot access the files I need at all.  (So I can't copy them anywhere.)

Comment: what you could try its downloading a linux OS like Ubuntu and dual booting it to see if you can get access to it or go into you BIOS and check you hard drive configuration

Comment: Depending on what you running at the moment switch from Sata IDE to AHCI or vice versa, that might solve the problem

Comment: I had tried that already, going to IDE gave the BSOD