# Partition does not have a volume

Tags: windows-7, windows, partitioning, diskpart

When I run DiskPart, I have a Disk 0 and a Disk 1.  On Disk 0 there are 3 partitions.  Partition 3 has a size of 238 GB.

When I run List Volume there is not a matching volume with a size of 238 GB.

**Is there a way to manually create a volume attached to this partition (without deleting the data on the partition!)?**

Comment: What is (what do you suspect is) on this partition?  Is the drive from another operating system?

Answer (score -2):

You need to `ASSIGN` a drive letter to that partition.
Assign assigns a drive letter to the selected partition, making it a 'volume'

```
Dispart> Select disk 0

Diskpart> Select partition 3

Diskpart> Assign
```

If there is data on that partition that is readable by windows, you will be able to see it.
If windows pops up a message that states, "you need to format the drive in (assigned letter)", you will need to give us more information!

Comment: I get the following result: "There is no volume specified. Please select a volume and try again." The Assign help text says that it is for the selected volume: "Assign  - Assign a drive letter or mount point to the selected volume."  From the help text, it seems as if Assign does not look at or care about the selected partition.